# How to implement setOnItemClickListener?

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I'm trying to add a listenner to my listview but I get many errors, including this one:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type The method

> setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type
>   AdapterView is not applicable for the arguments (new
>   OnItemClickListener(){})  GlossaryActivity.java   /line
>   109   Java Problem

Here is my code:

```
    // Initialize the UI components
    ListView GlossaryListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, TermsArray);
    GlossaryListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    GlossaryListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                View v, int position, long id) {
        }
    });
```

I placed this piece of code inside of onCreate method. How do I fix this

Comment: Did you try AdapterView.OnItemClickListener rather than just OnItemClickListener, and also do you have the correct imports?

Comment: Are you sure you're importing the right OnItemListener interface ? From android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

Comment: add them then, just implement which you want !

Comment: @AsTeR thanks , I did not have the correct import, now its all fine

Comment: please close/delete/answer your question to stop people from looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported the wrong interface (java one) the correct one is:

```
android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
```